# How to prevent selfdestruct from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I have a contract A calling another contract B

Contract A

```
contract A {

   function sendValue(B _externalContract, uint _value) {
     _externalContract.acceptValue(_value);
   }
}

contract B {
   function acceptValue(unit value);
}
```

Contract B (contract A expect contract B `acceptValue` to be safe)

```
  contract B {
       function acceptValue(unit _value) {
         dosomethingWith(_value)
       }
    }
```

If a malicious user now design contract B function `acceptValue` to self destruct like so

Contract B

```
  contract B {
       function acceptValue(unit _value) {
         selfdestruct(msg.sender);
       }
    }
```

- Will that function destroy my contract A or malicious user Contract B?
- Is there a check I can perform in contract A `sendValue` to prevent that?

Comment: In your code sample, Contract B would be destroyed via selfdestruct(...). The only case where Contract A would be destroyed is if Contract A would have done a delegatecall to Contract B. delegatecall would borrow the function from Contract B and run it in the context of Contract A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It destroys Contract B and sends B's Eth balance to contract A, if called from A.

There is no way B can destroy A. Otherwise, there would be chaos.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE and PSA**

If I'm not mistaken, if `A` uses `delegatecall` to `B` and `B` executes `selfdestruct` in the context of `A` then `A` will destroy itself. It's incredibly dangerous to use `delegatecall` with contracts that are not known and trusted. The documentation hints at that but the warning might not be clear to everyone.

The example doesn't use `delegatecall` so it's still not possible for a maliceous `B` to harm `A` but the PSA is help prevent anyone who comes across this answer from extrapolating the assurance in an unsafe way.

Comment: But there is - Chaos.

Comment: Updated the answer with a PSA